# Channel capacity and reference to Shannon's example using starving child

Tags: information-theory

I faintly recall an example proof for existence of a starving child as motivation for the channel capacity derivation.

I looked in MacKay's book, and elsewhere, but found nothing.

Can anyone point me to an on-line reference?

Thank you,

Mirko

Answer (score 0):

I found the example.  It is described at the start of Section 10.3 of MacKay's book (Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms)